# fastest nosql for a billions records

Tags: database

which nosql database can handle over a **billion** records in a table.
which nosql nosql database can fetch within a second out of a billion fields in one table.
I've been directed towards MongoDB and memcachedDB.

Comment: MangoDB? ........ MONGO perhaps?

Comment: @BrianGordon *rows?

Answer (score 2):

http://cassandra.apache.org/

Good enough for FB, probably good enough for everyone.  :)